# MarkLogic - Return data through API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

MarkLogic version 9.0-6.2

I have a custom rest API that takes a list of customerIds and returns the documents matching with the input customerId. I am making HTTP call to this REST API through python. I am dealing with 20000 customerIds and during the course, I learned that the calling MarkLogic API with 5000 customerIds for each HTTP call is giving me the optimal performance. I coded python to read each customerId and when ever the count is 5000, make an API call to MarkLogic.

However, just wondering if I can have MarkLogic receive all the 20000 customerIds in one call, but return only 5000 documents at a time, without any additional action from python (or any calling service).

Any thoughts highly appreciated!

Comment: I think the answer is no. You can use paging to make the API requests more generic, but for "push" behavior you would need something like WebSockets, which AFAIK cannot be done natively in MarkLogic and would require an intermediary.

Comment: I'd say, if you want to get the quickest answer for all of the id's, send multiple calls in parallel..